# Git status shows both remote and local changes

Tags: git, version-control

I was working with 2 local branches in git, let's call them alerts_v2 and . I made some changes to A, committed them, and then switched to B. I did some work in B and now after switching back to branch A, I have file changes from the remote branch mixed in with my local changes. So when I do a git status, I have a bunch of files being listed that I didn't change. My goal is to have my branch match the remote master as far as committed changes and then only have my local changes show up when I do a 'git status'.

Update:
I've pasted a copy of the reflog. Branch alerts_v2 corresponds to branch A in the above example. I actually worked with a couple of branches before switching back to alerts_v2 so branch B actually represents a few branches (but I don't think this is material).

Entry 23a03b7 is where I moved away from alerts_v2 and entry f6c143e is where I moved back.

```
31b259f HEAD@{1}: origin/master: updating HEAD
74aab0b HEAD@{2}: commit: Blap
31b259f HEAD@{3}: origin/master: updating HEAD
f6c143e HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from version to alerts_v2
31b259f HEAD@{5}: commit: Added version information popup
b2c9ce3 HEAD@{6}: origin/master: updating HEAD
f0c9b0c HEAD@{7}: commit: Blap
b2c9ce3 HEAD@{8}: origin/master: updating HEAD
abba6bc HEAD@{9}: commit: Blap
b2c9ce3 HEAD@{10}: origin/master: updating HEAD
34ecadc HEAD@{11}: commit: Blap
f3cb5f9 HEAD@{12}: commit: Blap
b2c9ce3 HEAD@{13}: origin/master: updating HEAD
3a8c25d HEAD@{14}: commit: Blap
b2c9ce3 HEAD@{15}: origin/master: updating HEAD
6820bd3 HEAD@{16}: pull : Merge made by recursive.
ad215b1 HEAD@{17}: commit: Blap
27bd651 HEAD@{18}: commit: Blap
e74af44 HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from e74af44ae40484d837e0295c1622731de1dcb84e to version
e74af44 HEAD@{20}: pull : Fast-forward
76bb1fa HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from ncli to master2
e74af44 HEAD@{22}: commit: Added download NCLI button
ed2d3c4 HEAD@{23}: origin/master: updating HEAD
9ad842a HEAD@{24}: pull : Merge made by recursive.
b99d663 HEAD@{25}: commit: Added download ncli button
e83d923 HEAD@{26}: origin/master: updating HEAD
719791a HEAD@{27}: commit: Added download NCLI button
9e613d1 HEAD@{28}: commit: Added download ncli button
e83d923 HEAD@{29}: origin/master: updating HEAD
a4d6d42 HEAD@{30}: pull : Merge made by recursive.
39f5fed HEAD@{31}: commit: Add NCLI download capability
76bb1fa HEAD@{32}: checkout: moving from 76bb1fa890089ca732322eba7ad9e74486e2bda1 to ncli
76bb1fa HEAD@{33}: checkout: moving from master to master2
9248d50 HEAD@{34}: commit: Blap
76bb1fa HEAD@{35}: origin/master: updating HEAD
23a03b7 HEAD@{36}: checkout: moving from alerts_v2 to master
f6c143e HEAD@{37}: commit: Blap
8a4b166 HEAD@{38}: commit: Blap
76bb1fa HEAD@{39}: pull : Fast-forward
d245574 HEAD@{40}: pull : Fast-forward
c1e5e92 HEAD@{41}: pull : Fast-forward
b8602a5 HEAD@{42}: commit: Changed Alert event handling
db06232 HEAD@{43}: origin/master: updating HEAD
e807ef7 HEAD@{44}: rebase: Commit
db06232 HEAD@{45}: checkout: moving from alerts_v2 to db06232a413d79fd5607c5618dce8a316efbe84
8cc089f HEAD@{46}: pull : Merge made by recursive.
c74acd9 HEAD@{47}: commit: Commit
4a0c135 HEAD@{48}: commit: Changed the name attribute in the AlertModel to map to Alert Type
ed087cd HEAD@{49}: origin/master: updating HEAD
3db4639 HEAD@{50}: commit: Changed the name attribute in the AlertModel to map to Alert Type
ed087cd HEAD@{51}: origin/master: updating HEAD
ecaea02 HEAD@{52}: commit: Changed the name attribute in the AlertModel to map to Alert Type
ed087cd HEAD@{53}: origin/master: updating HEAD
36323fa HEAD@{54}: pull : Merge made by recursive.
18034e5 HEAD@{55}: commit: Changed AlertMode name attribute to map to Alert Type
a46de98 HEAD@{56}: origin/master: updating HEAD
6fae22b HEAD@{57}: checkout: moving from alerts_patch1 to alerts_v2
8efde4b HEAD@{58}: checkout: moving from alerts_v2 to alerts_patch1
6fae22b HEAD@{59}: commit: Made some changes
a46de98 HEAD@{60}: checkout: moving from a46de98c050cfc8b61b5efccb20d0a271b3959d2 to alerts_v
a46de98 HEAD@{61}: checkout: moving from a46de98c050cfc8b61b5efccb20d0a271b3959d2 to events1
a46de98 HEAD@{62}: commit: Initial implementation of Alert Manager, Namespace Manager and Pol
5cfb8a2 HEAD@{63}: origin/master: updating HEAD
f978dae HEAD@{64}: commit: Initial implementation of Alert Manager, Namespace Manager and Pol
5cfb8a2 HEAD@{65}: origin/master: updating HEAD
```

Comment: It's not quite clear: is B a local or a remote branch?

Comment: Both A and B are local branches.

Comment: Git wouldn't let you have switched from B to A without either committing or stashing the changes you made in B. Or are the changes purely untracked (newly added) files?

Comment: I did commit the changes in B (as well as pushing them to origin/master) before switching back to A.

Comment: If the files were not in conflict and were not committed, they would show up as changes before and after checking out the other branch.

Comment: There were locally committed changes made in A before switching to B. Then all of the changes made to B were both committed and push before switching back to A. After switching back to A I did a 'git reset --soft origin/master' expecting that my locally committed changes from before would be uncommitted and would show up in a git status. But my git status (on A - my current branch) now also shows a bunch of changes that had been pushed to the remote repository.showing up in my git status.

Comment: I have suspicion that I might have done a 'git pull' on branch A without then doing a 'git rebase origin/master'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out (or switching) to a different branch when you have local changes will succeed as long as those changes do not create a conflict on the new branch. Those could be the changed files you are seeing, the pending work you had on branch B.

You can remove all changes to tracked files with a hard reset:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

But that will delete your changes, if you want to save them you can stash them:

```
git stash
```

Stashing will create a record of your changes and revert any tracked files to its state in `HEAD`. You can see a list of the stashes you have with `git stash list`.

When you move back to the correct branch you can retrieve the stash you saved with:

```
git stash pop
```

And some [stash documentation just in case](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html).